# Python Import modules...can't see what I'm missing

Tags: python

This has probably been answered somewhere on SO, but my searches are all bad. Ridicule me as appropriate...

I have a custom set of modules called Framework:

```
Framework/
    some_module/
        __init__.py
        module.py
    some_other_module/
        __init__.py
        ...
```

`Framework` is in my PYTHONPATH.  `some_module/__init__.py` looks like:

```
from module import ClassOne
from module import some_function
```

I want to be able to do `from some_module import ClassOne` in my code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No. I thought it wouldn't need one, because I never want to import the whole Framework.

Comment: What error are you seeing? I've reproduced this setup and can import `from some_module import ClassOne` as expected.

Comment: Are you trying to use the module when you are inside its directories? That sometimes causes a problem. See that the script importing the module is in a different directory.